# SSHFS to make remote external drive visible in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, sshfs

Host is running OpenSSH server at 192.168.1.23 and contains three drives:

- `/dev/sda` (Ubuntu OS running server) with `/home/<username>`
- `/dev/sdb` as a fixed drive with music, and
- `/dev/sdc` as an external USB drive with movies.

From the local network, Client can currently mount `/home/<username>` (from `/dev/sda`) as a local folder on Client, and make it visible under "Devices" in Nautilus, with:

```
test -e ~/SSHFS.192.168.1.23 || mkdir --mode 700 ~/SSHFS.192.168.1.23
sshfs 192.168.1.23:. ~/SSHFS.192.168.1.23 -p <port-number>
```

So, from the local network, how can Client SSHFS mount `/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sdc` **and view their contents in Nautilus**?

#### Extras

- If `<username>` and `<username2>` wish to **simultaneously read, transfer, or write to `/dev/sdc`**, for example, is SSHFS still appropriate?
- If `<username>` and `<username2>` wish to simultaneously read, transfer, or write to `/dev/sdc`, for example, **from outside the local network**, is SSHFS still appropriate?

Comment: You'll probably want to put the drives into the fstab to have them mounted automatically. You can then SSHFS mount their mount points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first of all, `/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sdc` need to be mounted on the remote system.

Mount the devices, (you'll need root privileges):

```
$ cd /mnt
$ mkdir music movies
$ mount /dev/sdb1 music
$ mount /dev/sdc1 movies
```

Now back on the client, open up Nautilus. Goto `File` -> `Connect to Server`. Fill in the menu that appears, be sure that the folder is either `/mnt/music` or `/mnt/movies`.

sample fstab entry

```
sshfs#$USER@far:/projects /home/$USER/far_projects fuse defaults,idmap=user 0 0
```

Note:

USER@far is the user name and server name you use to ssh into the server. :/projects is the path you use to the location of the mount on the server.

```
sshfs#your_user@your_server:/mnt/movies /home/your_user/movies fuse defaults,idmap=user 0 0
```

See also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSHFS

[image: connect_to_server]
[image: menu]

Comment: @bodhi.zazen oops, I wasn't thinking straight. I'll update it now.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not clear why `fstab` is included in the answer as `sshfs <IP>:/media/external_movies ~/movies` works without touching `fstab`

Comment: if you add an entry to fstab, your share will automatically mount when you boot. Otherwise, manually mounting it with sshfs ..... is necessary every time you boot. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab